# ASP Question - How to count # of characters?

Tags: asp.net

Today is the very first day I've ever even *seen* aspx, so, please bear with me...

Basically, I want to determine if a string is empty.  If it is empty, then I don't want anything to output, if it's not, then I want to output the string itself.

```
<%= o_handler.renderDDesc()%> //This is the string itself... If this is empty, then I want I want nothing to print
```

I tried:

```
<%if (o_handler.renderDDesc().length() > 0) { %>
<%= o_handler.renderDDesc()%>
<%}%>
```

But, that didn't seem to do anything.  I didn't get an error, but it also didn't appear?

Comment: is this classic ASP? or ASP.NET?

Comment: If the string is really empty, then writing it to the response stream really doesn't do anything anyway.  So you could probably just drop the IF condition and write it out regardless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%

string desc = o_handler.renderDesc();

if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(desc)) { 
Response.Write(desc);
}

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= !String.IsNullOrEmpty(o_handler.renderDDesc()) ? o_handler.renderDDesc() : ""%>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a ternary operator as follows:

```
<%=( o_Handler.IsNullOrEmpty() ? string.Empty : o_handler.renderDDesc() ); %>
```